# if statement isnot working in picture rotation

Tags: javascript

the counter isnt reset to 1 after 10 pictures. Why? It counts to endless.
I cant understand why its not working. After the counter reach 11 he must set to 1.
Please help me. I cant find a solution.

```
    <head>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

            <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                    var timer,

                            counter = 1,

                            changepic = function(pic){

                                    var src = pic.attr("src");

                                    counter = counter+1;

                                    if (counter == 11){ ## here is the prblem
                                    counter = 1;
                                    }

                                    pic.attr("src", src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('.')-1)+counter+".jpg")

                            };

                    $('img').hover(function(){

                            var $this = $(this);

                            timer = setInterval(function(){changepic($this);}, 1000);

                    }, function(){clearInterval(timer);});

            });

            </script>

    </head>

    <body>

            <table style="float&#58;left;">

            <tr><tr><td><img src="testbilder/test.1.jpg"><br>Text</td></tr> </tr>

            </table>

    </body>
```

how can i fix that?

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nbQnW/

Comment: Confirmed Juhana's comment. Works fine in IE9 (all I can test in while at work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to confirm that the problem is with counter. Add a log statement and see the log in Google Chrome's developer tools.

```
if (counter == 11){ ## here is the prblem
    counter = 1;
}
console.log('counter : '+counter);
```

after looking at your code... I think the problem is in this statement..

```
pic.attr("src", src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('.')-1)+counter+".jpg")
```

Because for counter=10... the value of src is,

src = 'testbilder/test.10.jpg'

now by src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('.')-1)+counter+".jpg") will work fine for counter upto 9 but for counter = 10... this will be

```
changepic = function(pic){
    var src = pic.attr("src");  // here src = 'testbinder/test.10.jpg'
    counter = counter+1;  // here counter = 11
    if (counter == 11){ 
        counter = 1; // here counter = 1
    }
        // now src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('.')-1) = 'testbinder/test.1'
        // src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('.')-1)+counter+".jpg"='testbinder/test.11.jpg'
        pic.attr("src", src.substring(0,src.lastIndexOf('.')-1)+counter+".jpg");

    };
}
```

To fix this problem change it to..

```
pic.attr("src", src.substring(0,src.indexOf('.')+1)+counter+".jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object testbilder/test.1.jpg has no method 'firstIndexOf'